# UWP templated control not getting focus

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I've created custom templated control and I'm using it as a "display" in my calculator app. It inherits directly from the `Control` class but I can't find a way to make it focusable by user's click. I'm overriding the `OnGotFocus` method to do some stuff but it's never fired.

I think there should be some property to enable the focus on click behaviour, but I haven't found it.

I know I could use the `Tapped` event or `OnTapped` method, but that's not what I need.

Here's my code in Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ResponsiveTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PageBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ResponsiveTextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Active">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Opacity="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundRestOpacity}"
                            />

                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            />

                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement2"
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            />

                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextElement"
                               Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                               Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                               VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                               AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                               />

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: What's wrong with handling focus on tapped? That's most likely how it's done inside the `TextBox` implementation. Also, if you could inherit from `TextBox` rather than `Control`, you might not need to implement your own focus logic at all.

Comment: I used to inherit from `TextBox`, but I was not able to fully disable the [selection](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/images/select-word.png) on phones which was flashing there everytime I tapped the TextBox so I decided to create my own control.

Comment: And with the Tapped event implementation you think that in Tapped event I should call `this.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);`? I was thinking that it could get the focus automatically just by setting some property to enable that behaviour...

Comment: I don't think there's a property for it. :) It's pretty safe to just call `this.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);`.

Comment: Now I've managed to make it work with the Tapped event. There was a bug in my code that was preventing it  from working properly with that event. Thanks man :)

Comment: BTW if I put my comments above as answer, would you be kind to accept it? :P

Comment: Of course :D I've put a bounty on it and you helped me, so why not :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comment section, to have a similar behavior as the `TextBox` control, you will need to manually call

```
this.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

inside its `Tapped` event handler.